# Unable to change options for ngx_pagespeed

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

I was able to successfully add ngx_pagespeed to my Nginx server at Digital Ocean. I did an automated install and rebuilt Nginx from source with the ngx_pagespeed module per this guide: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

The module seems to be working. for example I can see it is automatically converting my .jpg images to .webp. Also, `curl -I -p http://localhost| grep X-Page-Speed` returns the expected header: `X-Page-Speed: 1.13.35.2-0`.

However, I’m **not able to edit any options**. When I try to run something like `pagespeed rewrite_images on`, or even `pagespeed on`, I get an error `pagespeed: command not found`.

Per documentation `pagespeed` should be the command for Nginx: https://modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration

I tried a couple of other commands:

1. `whereis pagespeed` returns `pagespeed:`
2. `which pagespeed` returns nothing.

As far as I know these should be returning the full path, something like `/usr/bin/pagespeed`.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a command, it's a directive that should be put in your nginx.conf.
As per documentation:

> in Nginx you need to add several lines to your **nginx.conf**. In every server block where PageSpeed is enabled add:

```
pagespeed on;
```

It's a snippet from the configuration file. 
The same goes for other directives such as `pagespeed rewrite_images on`